# GeoJSON polygon map resize with browser window in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to make a map of just geojson boundaries, no basemap/tiles and want it to scale up/down when the window is resized to keep the full map visible and as large as possible.

While the `map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds())` in `window.addEventListener('resize', function(event)` works somewhat, it can get stuck remaining small, cut off some of the edges being too large and is overall wonky.

example jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6yt4ekxL/6/

```
var mapOptions = {
  attributionControl: false,
  zoomControl: false,
  zoomSnap: 0.02,
  zoomDelta: 0.08,
  scrollWheelZoom: false,
  touchZoom: false,
  doubleClickZoom: false,
  boxZoom: false,
  keyboard: false,
  dragging: false,
  background: "None",
};

var mapStyle = {
  color: "#1890ff",
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 0.85,
};


var map = L.map('map', mapOptions).setView([0, 0], 3);

layer = L.geoJSON(basemap, {
    style: mapStyle,
  })

map.addLayer(layer);
map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that while resizing window, `resize` events are continuously fired and new `map.fitBounds` requests interfere with the ones being executed.

Solution is to use `setTimeout` to delay execution of `map.fitBounds` a bit and cancel execution if new request is issued while waiting.

Relevant code could then look something like this:

```
var timeoutId = null;

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  if (timeoutId) clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
    timeoutId = null;
  }, 50);
}, true);
```